# Sensor Control Unit の使い方について

Tags: spresense

Sensor Control Unitを使ってspresenseを省電力で動作をさせてみたいのですが、チュートリアルやサンプルが見つからずどのように使ったら良いのかよくわかりません。どこかに解説サイトなどあるでしょうか？

Comment: 検索してみるとこの辺の記事が参考になるかも。[消費電力の推移、精密な電力解析 - SPRESENSEの消費電力を可視化して解析](https://www.aps-web.jp/academy/amp/10632/#i-3), [1.17. How to achieve 6µA current consumption on Mainboard - Spresense Hardware Documents](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_en.html#_how_to_achieve_6%C2%B5a_current_consumption_on_mainboard), [全CPUの電源をOFFにできる超低消費電力を極めたハードウェア - SPRESENSE：マルチコア×超低消費電力、エッジAIの最有力を目指した新たなる挑戦。](https://www.aps-web.jp/magazine/6225/#CPUOFF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sensor Control Unitの開発ガイド](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_sensor_control_unit)を見つけたのでURLを貼っておきます。

ここを見ると、いくつかSensor Control Unitを使ったドライバやサンプルコードへのリンクも載っていました。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/tree/master/examples/mag/mag_main.c
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/tree/master/examples/gyro/gyro_main.c
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/tree/master/examples/decimator/decimator_main.c

参考になれば。